# Active choices parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have active choices parameter installed in my Jenkins. Here I have to choose a value from the text file stored locally and then display this as a multi select option to the user.
For example, my text file can have an entry 1 - abc, 2 - def. The user has to see both the entries and can select either of them or both of them. This text file is maintained manually. I can have a third entry 3 - ghi and when I trigger the Jenkins job, I should see all the 3 entries.

Can anyone please help me out here?

Thank you in advance,
Rohit

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// create blank array/list to hold choice options for this parameter and also define any other variables.
def list = []
def file = "/opt/data/jenkins/jobs/dummy_dummy/workspace/somefile.txt"

// create a file handle named as textfile 
File textfile= new File(file) 

// now read each line from the file (using the file handle we created above)
textfile.eachLine { line -> 
        //add the entry to a list variable which we'll return at the end. 
        //The following will take care of any values which will have 
        //multiple '-' characters in the VALUE part 
    list.add(line.split('-')[1..-1].join(',').replaceAll(',','-'))
}

//Just fyi - return will work here, print/println will not work inside active choice groovy script / scriptler script for giving mychoice parameter the available options.
return list
```

Comment: For more, see reference post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45336944/how-to-get-ordered-defined-or-all-columns-except-or-after-or-before-a-given-col

Answer (score 0):

You can use a groovy script to parse file and return options, something like:

```
def list = []
File textfile= new File("path-to-file") 
textfile.eachline { line -> 
    //assuming you want only text values without a number
    list.add(line.split('-')[1]) }
return list
```

Also choose "choice type" for multiple values.

Comment: THank you Igor. I have added the code provided by you. But when I choose Build with parameters, ideally I should see abc, def, ghi etc, but I do not see anything...

Comment: @RohitSavanurkar Did you check your script? You can run it in http://<your-jenkins-server/script> and see if its return those values from the file.

Comment: @RohitSavanurkar What I ment is, you should first check if the script is correct. Please run it in Jenkins script console and paste the output

Comment: Hello @Igor. Not sure how to run in Jenkins script. Can you please tell me how do I do it? I mean run the Jenkins script.

Comment: @RohitSavanurkar as I mentioned, go to http://your_jenkins_url/script, paste there your script and see what is the output

Comment: @RohitSavanurkar Do you still need help? Igor, good solution but just fyi it'll not catch if his values per line have a `-` in it.