# Jenkins Active Choices Plugin, Dynamically fill checkbox parameters from yaml file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, yaml, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am new to Jenkins and keep exploring different plugins, articles everyday to learn something new about Jenkins.

I found that, the parameters can be filled before the build using the active choice parameter plugin from the json file uploaded to the Jenkins server. I had googled it but couldn't find the right explanation. The hint I got was the use of the Groovy script in the Active Choice parameter. If its possible, please let me know.

I appreciate [@Noam Helmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13110835/noam-helmer) for the reference, but how can i capture the group1, group2, group3, group4,... from below file. all, children, hosts no matter how many groups are added to this file, it will remain the same.

```yaml
all:
  children:
    group1:
      hosts:
        xyz4.axs: 
    group2:
      hosts:
        xyz5.adf: 
        xyz8.asf: 
    group3:
      hosts:
        xyz3.asd: 
        xyz6.ads: 
        xyz7.asd:
```

I tried the following script but was unable to get the group name.

```groovy
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
List groups = []
Yaml parser = new Yaml()
def example = parser.load(("/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/groups/hosts" as File).text)
for (details in example){
  groups.add(details)
}
println(groups)
```

Now, I don't know if I'm on the right track, please give me a hint.
Any help in advance would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382296/active-choices-parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer, once again thanks @NoamHelmer for replying.

```groovy
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
List groups = []
Yaml parser = new Yaml()
def example = parser.load(("path to file" as File).text)

for(anf in example.keySet()){
    groups.add(anf)
} 
        
for(inf in example.all.children.keySet()){
    groups.add(inf)  
}

return(groups)
```

the output will be :`[all, group1, group2, group3]`